# how to grep substring between two symbols?

Tags: linux, string, bash, parsing, grep

I have a string like this

```
registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-native/mirror/images/busybox:latest
```

How to grep string between **last** `/` and `:`?

In this case I need to get `busybox`

I tried `grep -Po '(?<=(/)).*(?=:)'` but this command returns string between **first** `/` and `:`

and in this case i get
`gitlab-org/cloud-native/mirror/images/busybox`

Comment: Change `.*` to `[^/]*`

Comment: Seems cleaner to use `awk '{print $(NF-1)}' FS='[/:]'`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler form :

```
grep -Po '.*/\K[^:]*'
```

Comment: this can output strings that are not **between** `/` and `:`. Consider: `a/b/c/d:e/g` or `a/b/c/d/e`.

Comment: Also, the question is ambiguous about what "last" refers to: eg. `a/b/c:d:e:f`

Comment: @jhnc really good points, my solution should apply fully to gitlab url though.